# fetch specific title in every page with nutch and solr

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, nutch, dismax

I have solr and nutch installed and my web page structure is that in every page the title is the same; e.g. Bank Something; but in every page there is a tag with an ID of TITLE, something like:

```
<div ID="TITLE"><h1>my page specific title</h1></div>
```

I want to add another field to solr like second Title that fetch my page specific title and search words in it.(indeed now my page specific title is in content field and i want to have this in other field)

How can I do this?!

Answer (score 0):

Check [Nutch Plugin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-978) which should allow you to extarct an element from a web page.